# httr::GET / xml2::read_html - Stuck/Frozen - No response

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr, xml2

I wanted to pick up some data from the health.usnews.com. I ran the following lines but both lines give me the exact same result - No response at all, R gets stuck on the line and I have to manually click on "interrupt R".

```
page_response <- httr::GET("https://health.usnews.com/")
# or 
page <- xml2::read_html("https://health.usnews.com/")
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It isn't a problem of the code.

Answer (score 1):

The website uses the user-agent header to detect web-scraper. Add a fake user-agent header, you'll able to get the result:

```
page_response <- httr::GET(
  "https://health.usnews.com/",
  config = httr::add_headers(
    `user-agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36"
  )
)
```

The problem though is most of the data is generated by JS. Idk what info you need but you're probably gonna need the V8 package to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I tried your code as-is and the R still gets stuck.

I did try using a proxy as well but I get the same result.

Comment: @AntrikshTewari The stuck thing is not related to R code then. You might try another computer.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I did use multiple PCs at different locations (and IPs) - same result.
I'll have to find another way to do this.